# Loading a Google Map API into wordpress post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I am trying to get a google map loaded into a post.

In the header i load:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/js/parking.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the post in wordpress i load:

```
<div id="map_div"></div>
```

You can see the .js here: http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/js/parking.js

The map does not show at all, so i am hoping you guys can help me with this.

Comment: You have to include your `parking.js` script last.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anto Jurković mentioned in the comments you need to include your `parking.js` at last.

You're initialize the map and other objects when these objects don't exist yet because your jquery and Google Maps are loaded later. Also you don't provide your API key when you load the maps javascript, so Google won't provide you the map.

So it must be:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/js/parking.js"></script>
```

[How you can get the API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#api_key) is documented in the official Google Maps v3 Documentation.

**TL;DR:** You'll get it with the Google Developer Console

Comment: Ive now tried this, so the sequence is as you have described, but this did not make any difference.

Comment: You're missing the APIkey in your googlemaps include, it must look like this: `<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>` I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked. It does not matter when the script is loaded, and the script should also be loaded using the functions.php in wordpress i found out.

The div should have a size property, and this resulted in the map being displayed